# What is known about "Japanese suicide bomb-infantrymen at Port Arthur during the 1904 – 1905 war"?

Tags: military, japan, russo-japanese-war

There's a [book review](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/13576270701430825) that briefly mentions these as:

> the case of the Japanese suicide bomb-infantrymen at Port Arthur during the 1904 – 1905 war with Russia.

A Reddit [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/ab6u18/comment/ecyoyd2/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) claims no such stuff happened though. (There are some quotes in that thread from some books on the 1904-1905 war, but while these mention ruinous frontal assaults, they don't mention any suicide bombing in that war.) So, what's the extent of knowledge on these? I can't seem to find much else about them.

Comment: It's odd: the 2007 book review reads like its comment is based on an eye-skip misreading of the Reddit post, conflating events in 1932 at Shanghai with those decades earlier at Port Arthur.  Maybe the Reddit poster is paraphrasing from pre 2007 account that the reviewer misread?

Comment: @kimchilover: the [2018] Reddit post didn't exist in 2007. That said, it's possible the review author made that confusion.

Comment: A *Later* book [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=fLNLEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&dq=1904+port+arthur+war+japanese+infantry+%22suicide%22+charges&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH_4nkvp6EAxXdIEQIHa2oATI4ChDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=1904%20port%20arthur%20war%20japanese%20infantry%20%22suicide%22%20charges&f=false) mentions infantry 'Human Bullets' being used to carry explosive charges into Russian lines..

Comment: @justCal: not super convincing. The term/notion of Nikudan is discussed at more length in the Reddit quotes, but not as carrying explosive charges.

Comment: Agreed. There is a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=AxwMAAAAYAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=human%20bullets&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q=explosives&f=false) from 1907 which might relate, *Human Bullets: A Soldier's Story of Port Arthur,* By Tadayoshi Sakurai, but I have found no applicable reference to explosives so far.

Comment: @Fizz Of course 2007 was before 2018. .  That's why I posit a pre 2007 source for the Reddit poster and for the reviewer, that the latter misread.

Comment: Which of the book/article references and external links at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Port_Arthur have you already consulted? Also, have you read https://www.ospreypublishing.com/us/port-arthur-190405-9781472855633/ and other books on this battle?